# JQuery JScroll for Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

currently I am working with JQuery plugin: JScroll to implement lazy load for my table. But, I don't know why, after I use following code:

```
$('#table-modify2').jscroll();
```

The lazy load still not working. Not working here means it will display all of my data every time I load the page.

For your information, the table's data come from database and I use JQuery AJAX to get the data.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#table-modify2').tablesorter();
    $('#table-modify2').jscroll();

    bericht();
});

function bericht()
{
    $.post("func/bericht.php",
    {

    },
    function(data)
    {
        con = displayResult(data);
        $('#table-modify2').find('tbody').html(con);
        $('#table-modify2').trigger('update');
        //$("#table-checkout").html(con);
    });
}

function displayResult(data)
{
    con = "";
    row = data.split("_");
    for(i=0,j=row.length-1;i<j;i++)
    {
        col = row[i].split("#");
        con += "<tr>";
        for(k=0,m=col.length;k<m;k++)
        {
            if(col[k] == "internal" || col[k] == "external" || col[k] == "dp")
            {
                if(col[k] == "internal")
                {
                    con += "<td class=small><input id = int type =radio checked disabled></td>";
                    con += "<td class=small></td>";
                    con += "<td class=small></td>";
                }
                else if(col[k] == "external")
                {
                    con += "<td class=small></td>";
                    con += "<td class=small><input id = int type =radio checked disabled></td>";
                    con += "<td class=small></td>";
                }
                else
                {
                    con += "<td class=small></td>";
                    con += "<td class=small></td>";
                    con += "<td class=small><input id = int type =radio checked disabled></td>";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                con += "<td>"+col[k]+"</td>";
            }
        }
        con += "</tr>";
    }
    //con += "</table>";
    return con;
}
```

Is there any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure on your ajax requests sent correctly?

Comment: yes i am sure about it.

Comment: So it results correct html data for you right?

Comment: yes. I have found out the problem, the problem is, I forgot to add "a" tag. But, after I add the "a" tag, the result is infinite load.

Comment: Where di you added that tag?

Comment: within the "tfoot" tag

Comment: it is not in your question

Comment: I just found it out. At first I dont realize, that's why it is not on my question